# NSFetchedResultsController create sections where date is nil

Tags: ios, ios6, nsfetchedresultscontroller, key-value-coding

I am using an NSFetchedResultsController and I would like to create two sections in my table based on a date field in my entity. I don't want to section based on the individual dates, but I'd like to have one section where that date field is nil and one section where that date field is not nil.

Is there a way to use the `sectionNameKeyPath` to achieve this? If not, how should I go about sectioning my fetched results table based on a nil vs non-nil value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the following *should* work:

- Use your `date` field as first sort descriptor.
- Define a transient attribute `sectionIdentifier` and use that as `sectionNameKeyPath`.
- Define the getter function for the transient property that returns only "0" or "1". In the simplest case (without caching), it would look like this:

  ```
  - (NSString *)sectionIdentifier
  {
     if (self.date == nil)
        return @"0";
     else
        return @"1";
  }
  ```
- Implement a custom `titleForHeaderInSection`:

  ```
  - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
      id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
      if ([[sectionInfo name] isEqualToString:@"0"])
          return @"Date is nil";
      else
          return @"Date is not nil";
  }
  ```

Comment: I haven't gotten a moment to test this out yet, but I haven't forgotten about you. I'll give this a try and respond soon.